# AoE effects with targets on top of each other

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

We've got a situation where a pit created by Create Pit is filled by ogres. Our witch decided to cast an [Ice Storm](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/iceStorm.html) on top of the pit. Should the damage hit the ogres in the bottom of the pit or are they shielded by their allies on top of them?
Our discussion ended with that they are we skip the potential crushing damage they would take.

Comment: The area of effect of the spell is listed as "cylinder (20-ft. radius, 40 ft. high)". Was the centre placed such that all the ogres were within the area of effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the PFSRD entry on Magic,

Under **[Aiming A Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell)**:

> When casting a cylinder-shaped spell, you select the spell's point of origin. This point is the center of a horizontal circle, and the spell shoots down from the circle, filling a cylinder. A cylinder-shaped spell ignores any obstructions within its area.

and later, under **[Line of Effect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Line-of-Effect)**

> You must have a clear line of effect to any target that you cast a spell on or to any space in which you wish to create an effect. You must have a clear line of effect to the point of origin of any spell you cast.
>
> A burst, cone, cylinder, or emanation spell affects only an area, creature, or object to which it has line of effect from its origin (a spherical burst's center point, a cone-shaped burst's starting point, a cylinder's circle, or an emanation's point of origin).
>
> An otherwise solid barrier with a hole of at least 1 square foot through it does not block a spell's line of effect. Such an opening means that the 5-foot length of wall containing the hole is no longer considered a barrier for purposes of a spell's line of effect

So from these two, we can see that cylinder-shaped spells origin point is the top of the area, which then extends downwards ignoring all obstructions (such as ogres). As the caster, all the witch needs line-of-effect to is the origin point, which here is the top of the ogre-hole.

At this point, the question is, *how well-packed are the ogres in this hole?* Unless they are so tightly packed as to constitute a solid barrier, with no gaps that meet or exceed 1 square foot, the spell will hit all of them (up to its height of 40ft and within its 20ft radius), not just the top tier of ogres.

Aside, kudos to your group for creating an ogre-hole.